# Create Password Verification Function Oracle 10g

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle10g

How is it possible to create a function in ORACLE to check the password?

The password should contain:

- at least 1 upper case
- at least 1 lower case
- at least 1 digit
- at least 8 characters long
- doesn't contain 3 consecutive letters of the user name

So far, I reached the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dd_pwd_fun(username varchar2, password varchar2)
RETURN BOOLEAN IS

PWD_STR VARCHAR2
USER_NAME

BEGIN

PWD_STR = password;
USER_NAME=username;

IF LENGTH(PWD_STR) < 8 THEN
RETURN FALSE;
END IF;

if regexp_like(:PWD_STR, '^.*[a-z].*$') -- this is for small letter from a -z
and regexp_like(:PWD_STR, '^.*[A-Z].*$') -- this is for capital letters
and regexp_like(:PWD_STR, '^.*[0-9].*$') -- this is for numbers
```

This is my first time working with Regular Expressions and I need some help finding out a solution for the last requirement and also I want to know if I'm on the right track

Comment: So you need help with regular expression or help with "how to enforce password complexity in Oracle" ?

Comment: For Enforcing the password, isn't what all I need is to add the verification function to the desired profile? 
I need help with regular expression or the regular PL/SQL in creating this function.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov Any idea or help?

Comment: You don't have to put much effort to write the UDF, Oracle provides such functions. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found this solution to be working

```
FOR i IN 1..LENGTH(PWD_STR)-2 LOOP
IF INSTR(LOWER(USER_NAME),SUBSTR(LOWER(PWD_STR),i,3)) > 0 THEN
RETURN FALSE;
END IF;
END LOOP;
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `LENGTH(PWD) - 2`?

Comment: The last two iterations are not required.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle provides a function to be compiled under SYS for password verification and it's complexity. You will find it in `$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/utlpwdmg.sql`.

With different releases, the function has been modified and new functions have been added. In 10g, the complexity check was quite simple. Before 12c, there were two functions `verify_function` (10g) and `verify_function_11G` (11g). With 12c, there are four more functions, `ora12c_verify_function` , `ora12c_strong_verify_function` and two helper functions `complexity_check` and `string_distance`.

Since you are on 10g, you could write your `UDF` to enforce a stronger `complexity check` in `password verification`. Search for the functions and it's content in newer versions, and apply similar logic in your UDF. Have a look at http://www.oradba.ch/2013/07/oracle-12c-new-password-verify-function/

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but that file doesn't contain any example regarding consecutive letters

Comment: Yes, just for that thing you need to write your own logic. And add it to the UDF. Let me know if you aren't able to write the logic for it.

Comment: I'm not able to, I'm trying to use Regular Expression but I can't get there...
I don't mind any way, whether using Regular Expression or the PL/SQL commands

Comment: Since the password can't be more than 8 characters, you could have 6 combinations of substr function. 1 to 3, 2 to 4.....and lastly 6 to 8.

Comment: The password should be at least 8 chars

Comment: if the username is jsmith, the password shouldn't contain jsm, smi, mith or ith ...

Comment: Correct, so `substr` should work fine. It would need 6 AND clause. I don't have access to DB right now to post a test case, give me sometime.

Comment: OK, will wait for you and meanwhile I will work with a solution too :)

Comment: Sure, thanks. Just few more hours and I get back to work. Per the timezone,  we are way too far ;-) smartphones are good anytime anywhere. But, accessing DB is not possible anytime anywhere just for a test case :-)

Answer (score 0):

As a general solution, I would push (too) toward using a [Password Complexity Verification function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/policies.htm#i1007341). Concerning your last requirement:

> - ...
> - doesn't contain 3 consecutive letters of the user name
>
> I need some help finding out a solution for the last requirement [...]

If performances aren't an issue, you could probably solve that at SQL level. For example:

> ```
> SELECT COUNT(*) INTO nbr_matching_chunk FROM (
>   -- Split name in 3 chars chunks
>   SELECT SUBSTR('Sylvain', LEVEL, 3) chunk
>   FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH('Sylvain')-2
> )
> NATURAL JOIN
> (
>   -- Split password in 3 chars chunks
>   SELECT SUBSTR('painsword', LEVEL, 3) chunk
>   FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH('painsword')-2
> )
> ```
>
> If `nbr_matching_chunk` is 0, there are no matching 3-letter sequence.
>
> <sub>Or course for sake of readability I've hard-coded `username` and `password`, but you should be able to replace that by your actual PL/SQL variables.</sub>

Then, you only have to wrap that in your profile's [`PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6010.htm#sthref7203).